# Android Not able to fetch JSON elements

Tags: android, json

I'm making a server call. I have stored this JSON,

`{"latitude":"18.520430","longitude":"73.856744"}`

in String location variable.

I'm not able fetch **latitude** and **longitude** for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) to parse the data. Since your data is in `String`, you have to parse it using `Float.ParseFloat` or `Double.parseDouble`.

```
String location = ...;
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(location);
float latitude = Float.parseFloat(object.getString("latitude"));
float longitude = Float.parseFloat(object.getString("longitude"));
```

**Note:** Make sure you wrap the code with try catch, because all the methods of `JSONObject` throws `JSONException`.